# Queen City Sitecore User Group First Meetup 2018 - 03rd January

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

1. Date/Time (local): Wednesday, 3 January 2018 at 6:00pm
2. Date/Time (UTC): Wednesday, 3 January 2018 at 11:00pm
3. Location: 5th floor of 1230 Elm St. in Manchester, NH
4. Event Details: [Meetup Details and RSVP](https://www.meetup.com/Queen-City-Sitecore-User-Group/events/245802250/)
5. Contact: [Meetup Organizers](https://www.meetup.com/Queen-City-Sitecore-User-Group)
6. Presentation:

   - “Don’t integrate your data, assimilate it. Bring your data into Sitecore with DEF." - **Chris Auer, Sitecore MVP - Bonfire**
   - Introducing Sitecore Forms – Empowering Digital Marketing on Sitecore 9 - **Amitabh Vyas**